# Customized C++ Syntax Highlighting in Eclipse CDT? (e.g. highlight all asserts)

Tags: c++, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt, highlighting

i just wanted to know if there is an easy way to tell Eclipse (Helios Service Release 1) that **every line in my code which is part of an assertion should be highlighted in a chosen color**.

I'm aware of the fact, that assertions could be arbitrarily complex, so that parsing is needed. But maybe Eclipse supports something like "highlight all occurences of this function" out of the box.

Thanks.

Sascha

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "which is **part of** an assertion". Do you mean every line starting with the 'assert' statement?

Comment: I want to have the full assertion to be highlighted. If the assertion s complex with a lot of chained boolean operations, in more than one line, the syntax highlighter has to be aware of all the brackets and has to count them for determining where the assertion is finished.